# (iOS) Get status description with AFNetworking in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetworking in my iOS project, and this is my code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [signinUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];    
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:signinUrl parameters:dicParam success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:operation.request.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", myString);
    }];
```

This code let to make connection with server correctly and I receive an answer, but I need to catch the code status with their description, I mean... catch something like that:

> status_code: 406 custom message

I can get status code but it is an integer, anyone have idea how I can get this custom message?

Comment: Do you mean you want to retrieve the message actually sent back by the server on the status line, or do you want to get the standard description that goes with the status code? Don't think the first one is possible. The second one you can get via `operation.response localizedStringForStatusCode:`.

Comment: Hello @jcaron, yes I mean the first option... You have some documentation that talks about it? Just because I need to justify this

Comment: Always difficult to prove a negative, but through `AFHTTPRequestionOperation` you get access to `NSHTTPURLResponse` (via `response`), and that only includes the numeric `statusCode`. Even using `NSURLSession` directly, I don't think you get access to that info either. Via standard iOS libraries, the only way to access it seems to be via `CFHTTPMessage`'s `CFHTTPMessageCopyResponseStatusLine`, which means going very low level, establishing streams yourself. http://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/xcode/ios/1151/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFHTTPTasks/CFHTTPTasks.html

Comment: Thanks @jcaron for information